# Entity getter different situation

Tags: angularjs, symfony, doctrine-orm, fosrestbundle, jmsserializerbundle

I have a Symfony2/AngularJS application and using FOSRestBundle with JMS Serializer Bundle.
For normal entities every thing works great but in one of my entities that contains a collection of messages (topic entity) I need to return subset of messages in different situations. 
For example for the Topic Entity Owner I want to return all messages of the topic for message owner I want to return just the message that posts with the message owner and for other users I don't want to return any messages but they can post a message on topic.

I'm not sure where to implement this. In the topic entity or in the controller or ...

Comment: Usually are used custom services and repository classes for such tasks..

Comment: I found this but I'm not sure where to use it: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#filtering-collections

Comment: `Criteria` is very useful when you want to get collection elements by simple  conditions. But it doesn't support joins. You can simply put this into entity class, e.g. : `public function getMessages() { $criteria = Criteria::create()->where(Criteria::expr()->eq('deleted', false)); return $this->messages->matching($criteria); }`

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: In the controller.

Long version:
That you have a Topic entity that holds a collection of messages does not mean that you are not allowed to use just the message entity. Thus in case you don't need a whole topic then you should not use it also. Instead use an (array of the) message entity directly in your controller. You can use the [findBy() or findOneBy()](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#by-simple-conditions) function to retrieve the message(s) you need.

Comment: Another possibility could be that you give your user entity also a collection of messages. This collection must then contain al the messages that has been written by that user. You can also give the User entity two collections of messages:  received messages and sent messages. 

Its your application :-)

Last idea: you can also create other entities. For example the entity MessageByUserList. I think the name of this entity tells you enough :-)